# JavaScript single line 'if' statement - best syntax, this alternative?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

It's been clearly put, although opinion none the less, that forgoing curly brackets on a single line `if` statement is not ideal for maintainability and readability.

But what about this?

```
if (lemons) { document.write("foo gave me a bar"); }
```

It's even more compressed, and if expanded, the curly brackets won't be forgotten. Are there any blatant problems, and if not, what are the considerations? I feel like it's still very readable, at least as much as a ternary operator anyway. It seems to me like ternary operators aren't suggested as much due to readability, although I feel like that that conclusion isn't quite as unanimous.

The evil twin in me wants to suggest this, although the syntax obviously isn't meant for it, and is probably just a bad idea.

```
(syntax) ? document.write("My evil twin emerges"): "";
```

Comment: Would be nice if JavaScript supported end of phrase conditionals: `document.write("My evil twin emerges") if lemons`

Comment: I think you might be thinking about the short if, else statement. (`variable = (condition) ? true-value : false-value;`.) Good luck.

Answer (score 465):

I've seen the short-circuiting behaviour of the `&&` operator used to achieve this, although people who are not accustomed to this may find it hard to read or even call it an anti-pattern:

```
lemons && document.write("foo gave me a bar");
```

Personally, I'll often use single-line `if` without brackets, like this:

```
if (lemons) document.write("foo gave me a bar");
```

If I need to add more statements in, I'll put the statements on the next line and add brackets. Since my IDE does automatic indentation, the maintainability objections to this practice are moot.

Comment: you should know what you are expecting, since empty string and 0 are falsy values, it will fail the execute the second statement

Comment: Of course, you can just as well put a more explicit boolean statement in there

Comment: @acjohnson55 What do you mean?

Comment: I meant that in response to Orlando. Should have used my @ sign. Basically just saying that your approach is still valid if you don't want to rely on truthyness/falseyness

Comment: The second statement will fail linting and is not recommended

Comment: @danwellman That depends on what linter you use and how you configure it.

Comment: you can configure linters not to warn against eval, but it doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it ;)

Comment: @PeterOlson why are the maintainability objections moot? What if any other developer happens to not use your IDE with its configuration.

Comment: A small aside: the short circuiting behaviour of some logical operators can, IMO, be an excellent way to control code execution i.e. you can set default values if a user hasn't defined one in their environment (say, with `const envVar = process.env.SOME_VARIABLE || defaultValue`) - but in the case of checking definition, I don't see it used as often. Another advantage of using if is being able to negate with `if !(lemons) yourCode`

Comment: you can't use the `&&` style with short circuiting functions (and returning early), you can do that with the bracket-less if one-liner.

Answer (score 206):

I use it like this:

```
alert(lemons ? "please give me a lemonade" : "then give me a beer")
```

Comment: `alert(lemons?"please give me a lemonade":"then give me a beer")`

Comment: What is this syntax or technique called?

Comment: @tufelkinder ternary operator— (condition) ? "valueIfTrue" : "valueIfFalse";

Answer (score 56):

As has already been stated, you can use:

#### && style

```
lemons && document.write("foo gave me a bar");
```

or

#### bracket-less style

```
if (lemons) document.write("foo gave me a bar");
```

## short-circuit return

If, however, you wish to use the one line `if` statement to short-circuit a function though, you'd need to go with the *bracket-less* version like so:

```
if (lemons) return "foo gave me a bar";
```

as

```
lemons && return "foo gave me a bar"; // does not work!
```

will give you a `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'return'`

Comment: In single line short-circuits, we can omit 'return' and it should work as expected.
```
lemons && "foo gave me a bar"; // works!
```

Comment: @siwalikm could you explain?  This is for the case where you don't want to return `lemons` (if it's falsey) -- you only want to return "foo gave me bar" when `lemons` is truthy.

Comment: if (lemons) return "foo gave me a bar"; this is wrong. It will give you "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Comment: @Fenec would you share the browser and version that causes you this error? This worked for me almost 2 years ago and continues to work for me.

Answer (score 55):

You could use this format, which is commonly used in PHP:

```
(lemon) ? document.write("foo gave me a bar") : document.write("if condition is FALSE");
```

Comment: You don't need brackets on the `lemon`.

Comment: Can be best practice to include () around a conditional statement - removes any confusion as to order of operations etc. for other developers.  I typically err towards specifying it except when there's no way for someone decently qualified to get confused.

Comment: `document.write(lemon ? "foo gave me a bar" : "if condition is FALSE");` :)

Comment: I like the brackets as to me they imply a boolean coercion.

Answer (score 29):

can use this,

```js
lemons ? alert("please give me a lemonade") : alert("then give me a beer");
```

explanation: if `lemons` is true then `alert("please give me a lemonade")`, if not, `alert("then give me a beer")`

Comment: `lemons? alert("please give me a fancy beer with a lemon wedge in it"): alert(please give me a beer")` FTFY

Comment: why not use just 
`alert(lemons ? "please give me a lemonade": "then give me a beer");`

Answer (score 26):

This one line is much cleaner.

```
if(dog) alert('bark bark');
```

I prefer this. hope it helps someone

Answer (score 24):

As a lot of people have said, if you're looking for an actual 1 line if then:

```
    if (Boolean_expression) do.something();
```

is preferred. However, if you're looking to do an if/else then ternary is your friend (and also super cool):

```
    (Boolean_expression) ? do.somethingForTrue() : do.somethingForFalse();
```

ALSO:

```
    var something = (Boolean_expression) ? trueValueHardware : falseATRON;
```

However, I saw one very cool example. Shouts to @Peter-Oslson for &&

```
    (Boolean_expression) && do.something();
```

Lastly, it's not an if statement but executing things in a loop with either a map/reduce or Promise.resolve() is fun too. Shouts to @brunettdan

Answer (score 17):

// Another simple example

```
 var a = 11;
 a == 10 ? alert("true") : alert("false");
```

Comment: why not simply.. `var a = 11; alert(a === 10);` ?

Comment: @ManuKaracho I see this problem a lot when working with ternary statements. I understand OP may have just been trying to write a simple one but it is rampant in the code I read at work.

Comment: ```alert(a === 10 ? "true" : "false")```

Comment: @JoshWood the alert will print booleans too, so you can just do `alert(a===10)` like Manu said.

Answer (score 13):

```
(i === 0 ? "true" : "false")
```

Comment: what does this technique call?

Answer (score 9):

I've seen many answers with many votes advocating using the ternary operator. The ternary is great if a) you do have an alternative option and b) you are returning a fairly simple value from a simple condition.  But...

The original question didn't have an alternative, and the ternary operator with only a single (real) branch forces you to return a confected answer.

`lemons ? "foo gave me a bar" : "who knows what you'll get back"`

I think the most common variation is `lemons ? 'foo...' : ''`, and, as you'll know from reading the myriad of articles for any language on true, false, truthy, falsey, null, nil, blank, empty (with our without ?) , you are entering a minefield (albeit a well documented minefield.)

As soon as any part of the ternary gets complicated you are better off with a more explicit form of conditional.

A long way to say that I am voting for `if (lemons) "foo"`.

Answer (score 6):

It can also be done using a single line when using `if` blocks like this:

```
if (blah)
    doThis();
```

It also works with `while` loops.

Comment: This will fail linting and is not recommended

Comment: The OP also asked for a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Example in arrow functions:

```
let somethingTrue = true
[1,2,3,4,5].map(i=>somethingTrue && i*2)
```

In promises:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(_=>checkTrueFalse && asyncFunc())
  .then(_=>{ .. })
```

Otherwise:

```
if(somethingTrue) thenDo()
```

If it's just a simple conditional, I prefer using **if(value)** whenever possible because the word **if** in the beginning of the statement says more about what's happening than paranthesis and questionmarks.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Old Method:**
if(x){
   add(x);
}
New Method:
x && add(x);
```

Even assign operation also we can do with round brackets

```
exp.includes('regexp_replace') && (exp = exp.replace(/,/g, '@&'));
```

Comment: "Even assign operation also we can do with round brackets". This is very interesting, I didn't know that it was possible to do assign operations inside these single-line operations.