# Is it correct to use one line for loop in JavaScript without curly brackets?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am familiar with one line `if statement`, i found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860654):

```
if (x==0) alert('zero');
```

Is it correct to use `for loop` one line:

```
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) alert(i);
```

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/Zrwg5/1/) works just fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye but i googled it. not found anywhere mentioning it. every where using the `{`.

Comment: Using braces after your `for` or `if` statement is safer against accidental coding errors and less likely for someone modifying/maintaining your code to make a mistake too.  It is not required, but just because something isn't required doesn't mean it's a best practice.  Semicolons at the end of a statement are often not required either, but it's a better practice to use them.

Comment: @Paul - yeah, this seems to me to be a dup of that one.

Comment: I always avoid this sort of thing. It'll run, but you never know how someone will read it somewhere down the line - think Apple's `goto fail` bug.

Comment: This is technically valid, but I would say it's a bad idea. I would *never* put something like that in my own code. One of the best habits I ever learned was to *always* use braces for all for/if/while/switch statements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both methods are valid in Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements

All Javascript cares about is what is immediately after the `for` statement. It can be a statement block (multiple statements in curly brackets) or a single statement.

This is true for nearly every control statement in Javascript.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is correct to only have one statement there. In fact, it is required by the language. A for statement has the syntax:

```
for (ExpressionNoIn ; Expression ; Expression) Statement
```

notice that it only includes only one `Statement`.

A `block` is a type of statement which is defined using curly brackets and contains a `StatementList`, so you can use a block for that statement, which is what you see when there are curly brackets.

You can also use any other statement there; it doesn't have to be a `block` statement.

Comment: I often see code golf like this `function norm2(a) {var sumsqr = 0; for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) sumsqr += a[i]*a[i]; return Math.sqrt(sumsqr);}`