# Javascript: var1 == true && (var2 = true)

Tags: javascript

I see in the code I am working on often the following code style;

```
var1 == true && (var2 = true)
```

After some testing I figured it comes down to:

```
if (var1 == true) {
  var2 = true;
}
```

Is this correct, or is there more to it? And why would anyone use this since the readability just dramatically reduces, since your assume at first glance it is just a check on two variables. So you really have to start looking at single or double equal sings and where the parentheses are, which just kinda, you know.. Just curious here..

Comment: That's correct and yes it is bad for readability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One-line if vs && in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704750/one-line-if-vs-in-javascript)

Comment: the first comparison with `true` is superfluous.

Comment: @ Nina, haha you're absolutely right, was ofcourse something else in the code, I should have catched that

Comment: @Nina Trying to increase the readability of an unreadable statement here, I think it fits the example though.

Comment: @Xufox I searched for a long time and could not find anything since searching on these type of questions is just so difficult. I think this question might be easier to find, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent. As far as I know, it is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), describing the fact that the interpreter will return false for the whole boolean expression as soon as one of its parts is falsy.

Indeed, in your example it DOES reduce readability. But I think of it as just another tool in your toolbox you may use when you feel it could be useful. Consider the following:

```
return user && user.name;
```

This is one example when I tend to use it. In this case, I think it's actually more readable than

```
if (user) {
  return user.name;
} else {
  return undefined; // or null or something alike
}
```

**UPDATE**

I want to give you another example when I consider this kinds of constructs useful. Think of ES6 arrow functions like `user => user.name`. It does not need `{}` to open a body since it just has one line. If you wish to log something to the console (for debugging), you would end up having

```
user => {
  console.log(user); // or something alike
  return user.name;
}
```

You might as well use the shorter variant

```
user => console.log(user) || user.name
```

since `console.log` returns `undefined` after logging into the console, hence `user.name` is returned.

Comment: I have to disagree on the readability, you might save some lines but it does not get any clearer. I suspect you might get used to this though if you use it a lot

Comment: @Bastiaan Yup. I think I would neither say "use it always" nor "never use it". It is just good to know every possibility you may have.

Comment: @SWSSchmidt, getting there not completely convinced yet :) You explanation though makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: This neat trick `user => console.log(user) || user.name` is quite helpful for fat arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you've mentioned there's more to it.

the first part `var1 == true` checks whether ther result is `true` or `false`.

if the condition is `false` the code after it doesn't get checked or evaluated and thus `var2` doesn't get set to `true`.

But if the first part of the condition  `var1 == true` is `true`  which obviously is true, the second part of the conditional statement the part after `&&` is checked.

now the second part of the condition is an operation it sets  `(var2 = true)` which is kind of a truthy operation.

we could edit your code a little bit to help you understand the operation more clearly:

```
   if( var1 === true && (var2 = true)){console.log('good');}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: so the functionality is the same in the two samples I provided.

Comment: well I won't put it this way, although the result is the same,  in the first example you are checking both `var1 === true`  AND the value of the operation `(var2 = true) `  itself whether it's  truthy/falsy 

so the entire line `var1 === true && (var2 = 'watever')` is a boolean condion

yes both example sets `var2` but in the first example you are also checking the result of the operation `var2 = true` yet not doing anything with the outcome

whereas in the second example you are only checking  var1 and setting var2 in case var1 was true..