# Best way to do conditional array methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

Assume we have function that returns array let's say 
`fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)` and i want to conditional reverse the returned array.

I know you can do something like this:

```
condition ? fn(parm1, parm2, parm3).reverse() : fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)
```

But in my case I don't want to call it twice. Not the array or even the function that calls the array.

So my question, is there something obvious to do and I've missed like

```
array[condition  && .reverse()]
```

or the first way is the only way to call array methods.

Comment: The function is not called twice. Do you mean written twice?

Comment: The function will be called *once*. Your problem does not exist ;)

Comment: For simplicity of reading/writing store array in variable before the conditional

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant written twice of course

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as default method.

```
result = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)[condition ? 'reverse' : 'slice']();
```

Instead of `slice` and to prevent to get a copy of the array, you could implement a function which turns just `this` from the object without mutating it.

```
Array.prototype.nop = function () { return this; };

result = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)[condition ? 'reverse' : 'nop']();
```

Comment: Why create a new array?

Comment: @JimmyJanson If the requirement is to not write the code twice why create the array twice?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't see where it is created twice...what do you mean?

Comment: @guest271314 How i create it twice? dont get it.

Comment: @JimmyJanson [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a new array

Comment: I use it without slice, like this:
result = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)[condition && 'reverse' ]();

Comment: @JimmyJanson How does `result = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)[condition && 'reverse']()` not throw an error if `condition` is `false`?

Comment: @JimmyJanson That would fail if condition is false

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, it is less efficient but I don't think it is noticeable with small datasets ;)

Comment: @Michelangelo See the requirement described at original Question _"But in my case I don't want to call it twice. Not the array or even the function that calls the array.

So my question, is there something obvious to do and I've missed like

`array[condition  && .reverse()]`"_ at comment  _"i meant written twice of course"_ 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115374/best-way-to-do-conditional-array-methods-in-javascript/47115417#comment81180627_47115374. If the requirement is to not do something twice, why do something twice? Though OP is free to accept or not to accept any Answer.

Comment: @Michelangelo Though OP is free to accept or not to accept whichever Answer they decide to.

Comment: @guest271314 you are completely right it is not the right answer because it creates the array twice

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, was not really clear to me what OP wanted. Thought he wanted to get rid of duplicate code or something like that.

Comment: @NinaScolz `.sort()` does not create a new array `result = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3)[condition ? "reverse" : "sort"]()`

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3);
condition && arr.reverse();
```

Comment: @NinaScholz `reverse` reverses the array in place, so the assignment isn't needed

Comment: @NinaScholz _"you need an assignment with `reverse`"_ Not sure what you mean? The code at Answer should meet requirement

Comment: This is the better answer, because it's more efficient (and less tricky).

Comment: How this is different from:
var arr = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3);
condition ? arr.reverse() : arr

Comment: @JimmyJanson What is the requirement? The original Question states that the object is to not write code twice, yet the code at your comment writes code twice

Comment: won't work for me can't declare variable arr inside the array where i try to execute it. fn is element inside another array.

Comment: @JimmyJanson _"won't work for me can't declare variable arr inside the array where i try to execute it. fn is element inside another array."_ How is that related to the requirement described at original Question? What do you mean by "inside the array"?

Comment: @ guest271314 like this [1, 2, 3, functionThatReturnsArray, 3]

Comment: Can you post actual code at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158235/discussion-between-jimmy-janson-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

I had an array I wanted to sort asc and desc.  The sort boolean and ternary operators led me to this.  Basically, if false then multiply by -1.  It could probably even be simplified beyond this.

```
data.items
.sort((a, b) =>
    new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date)
    ? -1 * (sort ? 1 : -1)
    : 1 * (sort ? 1 : -1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using sort? I am not sure if browsers and node.js have the same behaviour here though:

```
const arr = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3).sort(()=> INVERTED ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it easy to read and understand:

```
var arr = fn(parm1, parm2, parm3);
if (condition) {
    arr.reverse();
}
```

Tricky solutions won't be appreciated by people who will read your code in the future.

Comment: How this is different form @guest271314 answer?

Comment: As I wrote above, using the `if` keyword makes code easier to understand. This is, of course, a personal opinion, but I believe the majority agrees with it. It has been discussed earlier, read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704750/3219919