# Javascript one line If, only state true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, typescript

In default 'if' one line statement are two block, for true, and false:

```
variable ? true block : false block;
```

How declare 'if' with one block?

I expect something like this:

```
variable ? true block;
```

Comment: i think you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860654/javascript-single-line-if-statement-best-syntax-this-alternative

Comment: Lol it was literally the first result that came on Google. Did you even try to find an answer?

Answer (score 12):

```
if(variable) block;
```

With the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) you need the false bit also.

Comment: is it right to pass  just `null` for the false block, when we use the ternary?

Comment: You could. I wouldn't use it. I use ternary when I know I have 2 operations. If just care about the `true` or `false` condition I would use it this way. It's more a preference then anything @CeylanMumunKocabaş

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş—you can do that, but it's more to type and not as clear as using a simple *if*.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
variable && block
```

For example:

```
let variable = true;
let o = variable && 3;
```