# How to invoke functions and in an order of execution in ReactJS Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

In my reactjs application in which I have a functional component and `completed` is a state and it is defined as below using hooks.

```
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false)
```

Question 1:

When component renders for the first time i want to invoke a parameterized function `checkEmpty` without arguments inside useEffect as below. This `checkEmpty` function will return a boolean value. But the function below is not getting triggered inside `useEffect`. I want to make the code to invoke `checkEmpty` function and if it returns true the `completed` state should set to `true`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkEmpty && setCompleted(true)
}, [])
```

Question 2:

In the below code in onChange event i'm trying to invoke two function. I want to start the `checkEmpty` function only after the `setValue` function completes

```
onChange={ value=> {
    setValue(index, value),
    checkEmpty(value, index)
}}
```

Can anyone please help to solve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, in my opinion [it's preferable to use an explicit `if` condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860674/3103891), but if you insist you should *call* the `checkEmpty` function by adding parenthesis: `checkEmpty()`.
Without them, you're just checking if `checkEmpty` exists. Assuming it does - `setCompleted(true)` will always be invoked.

Secondly, if you want something to happen *after* a state changes, you can use the `useEffect` hook with the updated variable in its second argument.
So in your example, if you set `value`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  checkEmpty(value, index);
}, [value]);
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for the answer.
For my second question there is a small change ie, i want to change state of 'completed' on onChange event as below. So when defining it inside useEffect will result in an infinite loop right?

`onChange={ value=> {
    setValue(index, value),
    setCompleted(checkEmpty(value, index))
}}`

Comment: You're right. What's `completed`? Can it be stored in a `ref`?

Comment: Sorry it cant be. `completed` is used to update the UI when the `checkEmpty` returns true.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're going to need to re-think your component design, so it makes sense with the hooks principles