# How can I write promt value and get different answers with if else conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm learning javascript and I want to practice with this question's answers.

```js
var brand = prompt('Car brand?')
var model = prompt('Car model?')
var tank = prompt('Aracin yakit deposu ne kadar?')
var fuelPrice = 7.60
var fuelPriceTotal = (tank * fuelPrice)
var automatic = prompt('Otomatik mi?')

console.log(brand + ' ' + model + ' ' + tank + ' ' + 'litre yakit deposuna sahip toplam yakit fulleme fiyati' + ' ' +
  parseInt(fuelPriceTotal) + 'TL' + ' ' + 'Araç' + ' ' + automatic + 'tir')
```

My question is how can I make automatic part yes no question and if answer 'yes' then console writes x sentence else console writes y sentence? (english not my main language so dont over think string parts. just automatic part is main question.)

thanks.

I tried

```
if (automatic === 'yes') {
    console.log('Write one')
} else (automatic === 'no'){
    console.log('write number two')
}
```

Im pretty sure there is a bunch of problems here but I dont know what are those.

Comment: Here is a nice script for your day name you deleted: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/81a4tdxq/

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct, but in JavaScript, with the `if...else` statement, condition nesting is achieved using the `else if` clause.

```
if (automatic === 'yes') {
    console.log('Write one')
} else if (automatic === 'no'){ // You were missing the `if` here.
    console.log('write number two')
}
```

[Read more on the `if...else` statement on MDN, here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Hope this helps.

Comment: ı learned if you write else if you must finish it with last else condition. so is it wrong that I learned? Its worked btw thank you very much!!

Comment: It's not a syntax error to omit the `else` clause. In practice, it really depends on your use case. Here, for example, you might want to do something **only if** `automatic` is neither `'yes'` or `'no'`. In this scenario, you could use an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the else if syntactically wrong and also not needed:

```
if (automatic === 'yes') {
    console.log('Write one')
} else {
    console.log('write number two')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could also use [JavaScript's single line 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860654/javascript-single-line-if-statement-best-syntax-this-alternative)

You can do so with:

```
(automatic === 'yes') ? console.log('Write one') : console.log('Write number two')
```

However, if you have three values like 'yes', 'no' & 'disabled', then you might want to use the traditional if else statement:

```
if (automatic === 'yes') {
    console.log('Write one')
} else if (automatic === 'no'){
    console.log('write number two')
} else if (automatic === 'disabled'){
    console.log('write number three')
}
```

Comment: It is called called [Conditional_Operator or Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) but you are not using it in an appropriate manner. Instead do `console.log(automatic === 'yes' ? 'Write one' : 'Write number two')`

Comment: For the second example I suggest `let text = 'N/A'; if (answer === 'yes') { text = 'Text for yes'; } else if (answer === 'no') { text = 'Text for no')
}   console.log(text);`